# Python file is not getting document in doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen, document

I am trying to document my Python code using `doxygen` but some files are there which doesn't have python class structure they just have some python functions, so that `.py` files is not getting documented in `doxygen`.

Below is the config file:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "E-comm sale"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./output
INPUT                  = ./cars/auto
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.py \                         
RECURSIVE              = YES
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html    
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen? The line `FILE_PATTERNS  = *.py \  ` will cause problems as actually it reads: `FILE_PATTERNS          = *.py \
                         RECURSIVE \
                         = \
                         YES`  What is in a py file (please give a small example).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello @albert FILE_PATTERNS  = *.py \ is the files which we want to consider. its python files which having python functions and classes

Comment: Hello @Community my project is based on Python and there are multiple python files. so while documenting with doxygen its considering the only files which having python classes structure, but i want the all `.py` files in doxygen document. So I am not able add specific attribute in doxygen config if needed.

Comment: I know you would like to consider the python files, but the backslash should not be present in the example you gave. After correcting this and when it is stil not working, tou should give an example of what is not working, not just some attempt of a description.

Comment: by removing it also not getting same issue, I tried forward slash/back slash even with no slash

Comment: Any other suggestions guys, because still facing the same issue

Comment: Using Doxygen 1.9.4

Comment: You edited some things in your question regarding the settings, but you left the ```\``` this should not be there at all as it concatenates `RESCURSIVE = YES` to `INPUT` and thus not seeing the `RECURSIVE` setting at all (see my first comment), was your first comment based on the fact that ``\`` has been removed in the `INPUT` line?